# Sort musical pitches

Tags: code-golf, array, sorting, music

Given an unordered list of musical pitches, write the shortest program/function (scored in bytes) to sort the list from lowest pitch to highest.

Pitches will be given in [scientific pitch notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_pitch_notation), consisting of a tone name followed by an octave number. Here, the tone name will be a single letter A–G, possibly followed by a single `#` or `b` character (representing sharp and flat, respectively). The octave number will be a single digit 0–9.

From lowest to highest, the order of pitches in this notation may be represented as follows:

```
<--- lower pitch                              higher pitch --->
_______________________________________________________________
Cb0 C0 C#0
       Db0 D0 D#0
              Eb0 E0  E#0
                  Fb0 F0  F#0
                          Gb0 G0 G#0
                                 Ab0 A0 A#0
                                        Bb0 B0  B#0
                                            Cb1 C1  C#1
                                                    Db1 D1 D#1
                                                           etc.
```

In this representation, pitch rises from left to right, so vertically aligned notes ([enharmonic pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enharmonic)) have the same pitch. Each row contains three notes in the order flat, natural, sharp (e.g. Cb0, C0, C#0) and the order of rows within an octave is C, D, E, F, G, A, B. Notice that by a quirk of the notation, the indentation pattern differs for the C and F rows.

Your code may sort enharmonic pitches in any order. For example, given `[D#0, Eb0, D#0]` as input, any of `[D#0, D#0, Eb0]`, `[D#0, Eb0, D#0]`, and `[Eb0, D#0, D#0]` is a valid output.

#### Test cases

```
[A2, B2, C2, D2, E2, F2, G2, A3] -> [C2, D2, E2, F2, G2, A2, B2, A3]
[E5, D#5, E5, D#5, E5, B4, D5, C5, A4] -> [A4, B4, C5, D5, D#5, D#5, E5, E5, E5]
[E#6, Fb6, B#6, Cb7, C7] -> [Fb6, E#6, Cb7, B#6, C7] or [Fb6, E#6, Cb7, C7, B#6]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>31 30</s>  29 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
FµḢ“¤ı¶“Œ’ḥ;ṪV×12Ʋ;=”#Ḥ’ƊSµ$Þ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of lists of characters and yields a sorted version.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/t0NaHOxY9aphzaMmRjYe2ARlHJz1qmPlwx1LrhztXhR2ebmh0bJO17aOGucoPdywByhzrCj60VeXwvP8Pd2w63O79/7@rqYKLsqkCgnIyUXAxVXA2VXA0AQA)**

#### How?

```
FµḢ“¤ı¶“Œ’ḥ;ṪV×12Ʋ;=”#Ḥ’ƊSµ$Þ - Link: notes
                           $Þ - sort by: last two links as a monad:
 µ                            -   monadic chain:
F                             -     flatten (this is to get a copy so we don't
                                             alter what we are sorting in place)
                          µ   -   monadic chain:
  Ḣ                           -     head of note (removes it too)
          ḥ                   -     hash with salt & domain:
   “¤ı¶“Œ’                    -       base 250 numbers = [256628,20]
                                        X = CDEFGAB -> 4,6,8,9,11,13,15
                 Ʋ            -     last four links as a monad:
            Ṫ                 -       tail of note (removes it too)
             V                -       evaluate as Jelly code -> integer
               12             -       twelve
              ×               -       multiply
                                        Y = 12 × octave
           ;                  -     concatenate -> [X,Y]
                        Ɗ     -     last three links as a monad - f(v):
                                        (v being one of [], ['#'], or ['b'])
                   =”#        -       equals '#'? (vectorises)
                      Ḥ       -       double
                       ’      -       decrement
                                        O = accidental offsets [], [1], or [-1]
                  ;           -     concatenate -> [X,Y]+O
                         S    -     sum -> note number
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>92</s> 83 bytes

*-9 bytes thanks to [G B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/18535/g-b)*

### Golfed code

```python
lambda l:sorted(l,key=lambda i:12*int(i[-1])+" D EF G A B".find(i[0])-ord(i[1])/48)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xcy9DoIwAATg3adoytIKqPwohoSh5e8hCAMEiI0IBFl4@soZB8Py5dredVqXxzh4uouY7qtX3VSkD9/jvLQN661nu0a/WxU67lENC1OF7ZTcpCQhaUZyIoikp04NzfZyKbk9zkhb5ezfueaHacaqYwUVLrWoBDFIQAoykAPh0ZL/b9IrmgbcR@njjBQD4e@nxg1/11B@c1wHMEBRfwA)

### Commented code

```python
lambda l: sorted(l,                 # Sort the list 
    key=lambda i:                   # Key used to sort the list, takes a single string as input
                                    # Outputs an integer; the lower the integer, the lower the note
        12 * int(i[-1])             # Multiply the octave number by 12
        + " D EF G A B".find(i[0])  # Add the number of the note within that octave;
                                    # C = -1 up to B = 10
        -ord(i[1])/48               # Subtract the ASCII code of the second character; 
                                    # Ends up with sharpened notes having higher values than
                                    # no-accidental ones, which have a higher value than flattened ones
)
```

Comment: `+abs("b #".find(i[1]))` can be replaced by `-ord(i[1])/48`

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 99 bytes

```javascript
n=>n.sort((a,b,l=e=>`b${D=e.slice(-1)}#`.search(e[1])+12*D+'C D EF G A B'.search(e[0]))=>l(a)-l(b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY3BasMwEETv/QqBA9I2trHTtDnJYEtOPqIEIrlK4yCsYJlcSr/dnRZKaS45vNlZdmf3bK4mdmN/mbIhvLn5KOdBVkMewzgJYVKbeulkdbCLDy1dHn3fOZGV9Jkc8ujM2J2Eey33tCxXj3rJFdOs3bIdq1nD/xaKPZGsvDCUeWGJ5i4MMXiX@/AujoLXq5Q1QAENWrAFO1A/4dDF95PgKeNE9HATbp8RSiD/TLNGg6pAvb53InnBQwtpvp2yG8jmTkjZAlugBfrXl/A/g6S4yc9f)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>87 86</s>  85 bytes

*-1 thanks to [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)*

```javascript
a=>a.sort((a,b)=>(g=([a,b,c])=>(b|c)*12+' D EF G A B'.search(a)-!!c+2*(b<g))(a)-g(b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY29DoJAEIR7n@KAgl3@EhGlERL@H8JQ3J2AGsIZIFa@O8raGZpvZjaZ2Qd/8UmO9@fsDuraLG208Cjm3qTGGYA7AqMYugguX@vIek3iLdHa@7bJclaUrGIJS01vavgob8DR1TRp@xaIc4e45g4E4iLVMKm@8XrVQQsXPfF1h@kpMSPmxIJYEitictBrxN3/QHGkkkGyEdKATuQzYhJsDxkneilI0l/KREgSrpXlAw)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                  // a[] = input array
a.sort((a, b) =>      // for each pair of notes (a, b) to be sorted:
  ( g =               //   g is a helper function taking a note
    ([a, b, c]) =>    //   split into [a, b, c] (c may be undefined)
      (b | c)         //     use whichever of b or c is a digit ...
      * 12            //     ... as the octave
      + ' D EF G A B' //     add the index of the leading letter:
        .search(a)    //       "CDEFGAB" -> [-1,1,3,4,6,8,10]
      - !!c           //     subtract 1 if there's an accidental
      + 2 * (b < g)   //     add 2 if the accidental is '#'
  )(a)                //   invoke g with the 1st note
  - g(b)              //   invoke g with the 2nd note and subtract
)                     // end of sort()
```

Comment: `c||b` => `c|b`

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 83 bytes

Prompts for notes as nested vector

```
m←⊃3↑¨¯1⌽¨s←⎕⋄s[⍋((¯1×m[;3]='b')+m[;3]='#')+(12×(⍎¨m[;1]))+¯1+'C D EF G A B'⍳m[;2]]
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog APL Classic](https://tio.run/##XY29CoJgFIb37yo@cDiKNKj9DNGgZhEUXUA4aFEESoFTc1FRKTVEt@DW0Nxid3JuxM6pppaH55z3/ATLqDJZBdFiVhlHQZLMxyVm10Eft2dLkPWGZIbA/W5axqR4WFu4vRR5cTfw9CzyhJvZFY@bZITpUVUpeN3iUdPyWxCCpv9UIVUN83VTMc2KnLqGr2k6Tevgyrb0OrIrbekApg8KTd8v6akopwJsEyQ4DJfRZniMDqPLsC0QNOnVOFeY/@pUuWZzGXb1u6DU@U7IdD7uhg1mA8Qb)

Here is an improved 68 byte version but it does not work on Dyalog because of ⎕fi

```
s[⍋∊(¯1+'C D EF G A B'⍳↑¨s)+(+/¨((⊂'b#')∊¨s)×¨⊂¯1 1)+12×+/¨⎕fi¨¨s←⎕]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 70 bytes

```ruby
->l{l.sort_by{|x|x[-1].ord*12+"C D EF G A B".index(x[0])-x[1].ord/48}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzdSsNAFITvfYphF8GfTUxOsq03CvuT5CGWpbDUglCsRMUtbZ89nii2F/MNzJwz41faT5unqXjeHrblx278XKX94ZiPORR1LHfj@q6me@Hg0fUYYGBF@fq2fsk3OVTxtsjh7@yhfTydpndsQhAm1UIJK4npUsP0smKaNHOoRIxX8@X1dzAES3AET@gIPWEgmCZGyOBIcaw4V1wobhQMy87enCc6DS81LmZbeA2nYdrfHdPyD8tp3psl/9GddVmTC/RpAcvu0hJuGeP0Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 95 bytes

```
\d
$*-===$&
-
12$*=
(.+?)=+
$1$&
#=
==
b=

[CDE]=
$&=
T`L`56d`.=
\d=
$*=$&$*=
O$`.+?(=+).
$1
=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcuxDoIwGEXh/b4GlSBcSKgUpj8GSnExcdBNTCrBwcXB@Gw@gC@GdXI6yUm@5@11f1yXVXL0XMYZKs1FRMXIUWqVCpIi264lgyrDjAQimAQ4295dBCoWnPzem3r2hWCcw0oD/8mD8sEmkq2LoCFYPm9waTU7TavZazrNQXOn2W7gDPvI8J@uYm9oDdsKLqo5TDW7UDs1tM0X) Takes newline-separated input but link is to test suite that converts from and to comma-separated input. Explanation:

```
\d
$*-===$&
-
12$*=
```

Representing the pitch in unary using `=` signs, multiply the octave by `12` and add `3` (so that I can subtract `2` from it later without it falling to zero).

```
(.+?)=+
$1$&
```

Duplicate the note name.

```
#=
==
b=
```

Adjust the pitch for a sharp or a flat.

```
[CDE]=
$&=
T`L`56d`.=
\d=
$*=$&$*=
```

Adjust the pitch according to the note name.

```
O$`.+?(=+).
$1
```

Sort by the pitch.

```
=
```

Delete all of the `=` signs.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 81 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.sort((a,b)=>(g=([a,b,c])=>(c|b)*7+('0x'+a-5||4)%7-(c?b>g?.6:-.6:0))(a)-g(b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3NCoJQEIX3PUUo4Ux6RcofCFTUrIcQF/feVArxhkq08N1Np120mO@cMzBnHvzFB9nfnyPr1K2a63DmYcTtQfUjALcEhhE0IRSLtWS5JjkJ3AcmGM7bMDnzpsnFXcBAxiJqYts/sWUcRODIGhCIs1TdoNrKblUDNRRactCsrZYSM@KZmBMvxCsxOWol4ua3IPfoSCf5E1KXVuQzYuL@L9J9eilI0m/KREASrCfzBw)

Notice that we needn't care whether difference between each pair of letter is 1/2 or 1, just give them 3/4 works

```javascript
    #C    #D    #E    #F    #G    #A    #B
 C     D     E     F     G     A     B     C
  bD    bE    bF    bG    bA    bB    bC
[][  ][][  ][  ][  ][  ][][  ][][  ][  ][  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 59 bytes

A port of [@G B' Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/244119/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY9BT4MwFMfvfIqXcmmdImzIjAlLWmBcNj3saJaFjs5gSCFrDzXGz47ySMwOxl1@v76m7//6zLFqq6GT7@poYVs1GpSzStcGeN/Dp@dBrU5gurN97qwyT0A3jbGvO3tu9Ns@XV1WDNLhEIxvxQd16coFbWXsTTSfkQxyKNZQAgdBgkbXyr2cqKMhY3eORuw@fmQDQP@TY1tNf@fhNEq4jMgtEOHPR2VyMSr3w1FcosqQMMa8fzKwV0wJyBxZINfIEskXV6KKh2k@6o9CxHiF5wzJ42uRfoLfkMm0aDItukQtsflr@AY)

```scala
_.sortBy(x=>x.last*12+"C D EF G A B".indexOf(x(0))-x(1)/48)
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hU9Na4NAFLznVwzm4vbDxsQmpZDCaowU@nHosfSwxk1jkTW4S0ko/nbrPqVSKM1l5r3dmXnv6Y0oRNOU6YfcGDyKXEEejFSZBt/v8TUCMrmFLivzVBqpXWXxFg@5Nq8vpsrV@xv73WJJNoCknrWGR/Jhedd/AZ@iIEG0E5VuLbb2TGlbXlXi2Mt@JF4htGkF98rgDP4U53AirBCvkYAjdLxcZfLwvHUHy06KjOFyCHF91kdcIbihETVrqR61sG@3N4Vyh1vtVa7DU9@5gBOOp5aidGZpNZ5Y4ilRMnEYY/9lkDfsEghXhDHhmjAh5LMTUfF1N5/ojyYM6InqiJAHpyLHc1ojnXeHzrtDF0QLMtdN8w0)

```scala
object Main extends App {
  def sortNotes(notes: List[String]): List[String] = {
    notes.sortBy(note => {
      val noteChars = note.toCharArray
      noteChars.last.toInt * 12 + "C D EF G A B".indexOf(noteChars.head) - noteChars(1).toInt / 48
    })
  }

  println(sortNotes(List("Ab1", "B#2", "Cb3", "D#0", "Ab0", "G0")))
  println(sortNotes(List("A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2", "F2", "G2", "A3")))
  println(sortNotes(List("E5", "D#5", "E5", "D#5", "E5", "B4", "D5", "C5", "A4")))
  println(sortNotes(List("E#6", "Fb6", "B#6", "Cb7", "C7")))
}
```